# classes are not taking action on other pages in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using `ngRoute` in angular. The routing works fine, but `page 1` and `page 2` are not being styled. In my css file I'm just simply changing the background color for testing.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "main.css"> 
    <script src =   "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src = "main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app = "app"> 
    <div class = "page {{pageClass}}" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS file:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute" , "ngAnimate"]); 

app.config(function($routeProvider) { 
$routeProvider
    .when("/" , { 
        templateUrl: "intro.html", 
        controller: "intro-controller"
    })
    .when("/page1" , { 
        templateUrl: "page1.html", 
        controller: "page1-controller"
    })
    .when("/page2" , { 
        templateUrl: "page2.html", 
        controller: "page2-controller"
    })
}); 

app.controller("intro-controller" , function($scope) { 
  $scope.pageClass = "intro";
});
app.controller("page1-controller" , function($scope) { 
  $scope.pageClass = "page1";
});  
app.controller("page2-controller" , function($scope) { 
  $scope.pageClass = "page2";
});
```

This is my css file

```
.page { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.intro { 
  background: blue; 
}
.page1 { 
  background: red; 
}
.page2 { 
  background: green; 
}
```

Comment: It will be easy to debug if you can put a plunkr for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class` you add *dynamically* is not right - you should be using `ng-class` attribute like this:

```
<div ng-class="['page', pageClass]" ng-view>
```

See a demo below - guess you can fix the issue with your code now:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "intro.html",
      controller: "intro-controller"
    })
    .when("/page1", {
      templateUrl: "page1.html",
      controller: "page1-controller"
    })
    .when("/page2", {
      templateUrl: "page2.html",
      controller: "page2-controller"
    })
});

app.controller("intro-controller", function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.pageClass = "intro";
  $scope.next = function() {
    $location.url("page1");
  }
});
app.controller("page1-controller", function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.pageClass = "page1";
  $scope.next = function() {
    $location.url("page2");
  }
  $scope.back = function() {
    $location.url("/");
  }
});
app.controller("page2-controller", function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.pageClass = "page2";
  $scope.back = function() {
    $location.url("page1");
  }
});
```

```css
.page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.intro {
  background: blue;
}
.page1 {
  background: red;
}
.page2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-class="['page', pageClass]" ng-view>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="intro.html">
    INTRO
    <div ng-click="next()">Next</div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="page1.html">
    PAGE 1
    <div ng-click="next()">Next</div>
    <div ng-click="back()">Back</div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="page2.html">
    PAGE 2
    <div ng-click="back()">Back</div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried that, and i received the same result. The intro page is being styled appropriately, but page 1 and page 2 no

Comment: this makes sense , but my whole purpose was routing to different pages. My intro page is working fine but when i route the pages the styles are not coming in. This use to work for me , but im not sure if there was an update or something

Comment: yeah , your way of writing everything out was better , i didn't think of it that way . Thanks !